# How can I extract specific string in Linux?

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm a newbie in Bash and I had a difficulty on how I will get the specific string in my file below:

```
  DS*SC*S45WG*X56558*2
  NE*823*2*SC*q345w45*DT*RTD*7530SRT
  RJTROIT**20140617
  SNA**TP*55
  DS*SC*S45WG*X56558*2
  NE*17*2*SC*211*DT*DFS*75304KSRTRSHT**20140617
  RSS**TP*55
  DS*SC*S45WG*X56558*2
  NE*18*1*SC*3435*DT*PR*753SLRT
  JSRT**20140617~RSS**TP*55
  DS*SC*S45WG*X56558*1
  NE*19*1*SC*ERS*DT*DFS*753048SRY
  TSERY4654**20140617~RSS**TP*60
  DS*SC*S45WG*X56558*1
  NE*19*1*SC*FRAE*DT*ESS*753048499RYTSR**20140722
  RSS**TP*140
  DS*SC*S45WG*X56558*1
  NE*73*46464
  SD**15769
  SNA*PUI*000015769
```

With this file I have stated above, I want to get all these following data/values:

```
7530SRTRJTROIT
75304KSRTRSHT
753SLRTJSRT
753048SRYTSERY4654
753048499RYTSR
```

(those next to NE*823*2*SC*q345w45*DT*RTD for example). Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to do with those values? Output the lines containing them?

Comment: I want to get only those data and display them.

Comment: Are you looking for 75304KSRTRSHT or 75304KSRTRSHTRSS, I mean is multiline values what yo need? Could we consider RSS**TP or SNA**TP the end of the delimiter of your strings?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify what differentiates the values you want from those you don't. You have given us a magic list of values without explaining that they are, for example, the last field of lines beginning with X. How can we know which values you want and which ones you don't want?

Comment: Unless you explain how you get from the first to the second, there's no way anybody can help you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the values that you are interested in seem to be split on multiple lines, I would rely on a pure perl regexp to match the right patterns:

```
cat file.txt | perl -e 's/\s//g && print "$_\n" for join("", <>) =~ /\*([\w\s]+)[~]{0,1}\w{3}\*\*TP/gm'
```

Note: I've made the assumption that the values you're looking for ends with this delimiter:

`XXX**TP` where `XXX` could be `RSS` or `SNA` in your example.

**How it works**

- `join("", <>)` is creating a single string from the result of the `cat` command
- that I use to parse (the `=~` operator) using this regular expression:

  `/\*([\w\s]+)[~]{0,1}\w{3}\*\*TP/gm`

  This regexp looks for strings beginning with a star `\*` and made of [A-Za-z0-9_] characters (shortcut is `\w` for words) and spaces `\s`, a possible `~` (0 or 1 time) and then 3 word characters (e.g: `RSS` or `SNA`) two stars `\*\*` followed by `TP`.

  Parenthesis are used to capture only the pattern enclosed between them.

  `/gm` are regexp modifiers where `g` will return all the matches strings (not only the first one) and `m` allows multiline searches.
- The `for` statement loops over all the results and call for each match found `s/\s//g && print "$_\n"`.

  `s/\s//g` removes all the spaces (including carriage returns) and `print "$_\n"` output the final result (`$_` being the current value of in the for loop)

It gives me the expected values (without hardcoding them in the command):

```
7530SRTRJTROIT
75304KSRTRSHT
753SLRTJSRT
753048SRYTSERY4654
753048499RYTSR
```

---

**Update**: (to include the date pattern)

Please use the following command now:

```
cat file.txt | perl -e 'for$a(join("", <>)=~/\*([A-Z0-9\s]+?)\*\*\d{8}/g){$a=~s/\s+//g;print"$a\n"}'
```

Comment: @Sylvain Pineau: I tried the code but it doesn't generate any output. Any idea?

Comment: @Anne Please try my updated command, I'm taking into account the spaces that you may have on each line start.

Comment: @ Sylvain Pineau:The code works great. Just needing an explanation about the code. Can you please explain?Thanks.

Comment: :I would to ask additional question, I had a hard time getting the same data since there where some changes with the  content of my file - a date before RSS or SNA and other values. How can I make some update with your code? Please refer to the file above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cat` to display the file and `grep` to get only lines with the vaues you want.

e.g.: `cat myfile | grep 7530SRTRJTROIT`

or to get multiple vaues you can use `egrep` which alows regular expressions:
`egrep "7530SRTRJTROIT|75304KSRTRSHT|753SLRTJSRT|753048SRYTSERY4654|753048499RYTSR" myfile`

Comment: I think it's too specific. How about I will parse other data aside from **7530SRTRJTROIT**

Comment: Just replace 7530SRTRJTROIT with the string you want to search for. When using egrep just add all the string you want to search for seperated by |

Comment: @Pabi: your egrep command won't match `7530SRTRJTROIT` as this one is split on two lines (it's not the only one). Moreover you could also use `-o` to only print the matched patterns.